# Html Table Printing issue

Tags: html, css

We have an issue on the table while printing/print preview, according to our requirement, the table contains no repeating header each page while printing, but the starting `tr` on a new page looks weird with no space and border on top. Is there any solution for this issue? 
[image]

Comment: Usually a good idea to add some code to your question to make it easier for people to understand and answer your question... also to prevent getting downvoted in some instances. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Its a simple table with tr and tds, the issue is while printing that is why i attached the image. Our requirement is that we dont need repeating header [solved] . But tr on the next have no separation and spacing[not solved]

Comment: @F1CabService I have updated the code. Please check

Answer (score 0):

Try using `page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto`.
This will bring out the default behavior in page break.
Here is an example.

```css
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
@media print {
    table { page-break-inside:auto }
    tr    { page-break-inside:avoid; page-break-after:auto }
}
```

```html
<h2>HTML Table</h2>
<button type="button" onClick="window.print()">Print</button>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Contact</th>
        <th>Country</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
        <td>Maria Anders</td>
        <td>Germany</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
        <td>Francisco Chang</td>
        <td>Mexico</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Ernst Handel</td>
        <td>Roland Mendel</td>
        <td>Austria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Island Trading</td>
        <td>Helen Bennett</td>
        <td>UK</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
        <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
        <td>Canada</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
        <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
        <td>Italy</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: No this is not i am looking. We dont need header repeat on the next page. The "tr" on the next page have no border top and spacing that is the issue

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to prevent the page breaking your elements. Include within your `@media-print` section of the CSS:

```
@media print {
    table {page-break-inside: avoid;}
}
```

play around with using `table` or `th`, one of them could work. Note I have not tested this yet.

Here is a reference to read more about this [on w3schools.](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebi.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Remove thead form. it stop repeating header on print

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        table {
            font-family: arial, sans-serif;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            width: 100%;
        }

        td,
        th {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #dddddd;
        }

        @media print {
            thead {
                display: table-header-group;
            }
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <h2>HTML Table</h2>
    <button type="button" onClick="window.print()">Print</button>
    <table>

            <tr>
                <th>Company</th>
                <th>Contact</th>
                <th>Country</th>
            </tr>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                <td>Maria Anders</td>
                <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                <td>Mexico</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ernst Handel</td>
                <td>Roland Mendel</td>
                <td>Austria</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Island Trading</td>
                <td>Helen Bennett</td>
                <td>UK</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
                <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
                <td>Canada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
                <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
                <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                <td>Maria Anders</td>
                <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                <td>Mexico</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ernst Handel</td>
                <td>Roland Mendel</td>
                <td>Austria</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Island Trading</td>
                <td>Helen Bennett</td>
                <td>UK</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
                <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
                <td>Canada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
                <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
                <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                <td>Maria Anders</td>
                <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                <td>Mexico</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ernst Handel</td>
                <td>Roland Mendel</td>
                <td>Austria</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Island Trading</td>
                <td>Helen Bennett</td>
                <td>UK</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
                <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
                <td>Canada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
                <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
                <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                <td>Maria Anders</td>
                <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                <td>Mexico</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ernst Handel</td>
                <td>Roland Mendel</td>
                <td>Austria</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Island Trading</td>
                <td>Helen Bennett</td>
                <td>UK</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
                <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
                <td>Canada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
                <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
                <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                <td>Maria Anders</td>
                <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                <td>Mexico</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ernst Handel</td>
                <td>Roland Mendel</td>
                <td>Austria</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Island Trading</td>
                <td>Helen Bennett</td>
                <td>UK</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
                <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
                <td>Canada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
                <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
                <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                <td>Maria Anders</td>
                <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                <td>Mexico</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ernst Handel</td>
                <td>Roland Mendel</td>
                <td>Austria</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Island Trading</td>
                <td>Helen Bennett</td>
                <td>UK</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
                <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
                <td>Canada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
                <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
                <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                <td>Maria Anders</td>
                <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                <td>Mexico</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ernst Handel</td>
                <td>Roland Mendel</td>
                <td>Austria</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Island Trading</td>
                <td>Helen Bennett</td>
                <td>UK</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
                <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
                <td>Canada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
                <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
                <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                <td>Maria Anders</td>
                <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                <td>Mexico</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ernst Handel</td>
                <td>Roland Mendel</td>
                <td>Austria</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Island Trading</td>
                <td>Helen Bennett</td>
                <td>UK</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
                <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
                <td>Canada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
                <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
                <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                <td>Maria Anders</td>
                <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                <td>Mexico</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ernst Handel</td>
                <td>Roland Mendel</td>
                <td>Austria</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Island Trading</td>
                <td>Helen Bennett</td>
                <td>UK</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
                <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
                <td>Canada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
                <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
                <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
                <td>Maria Anders</td>
                <td>Germany</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
                <td>Francisco Chang</td>
                <td>Mexico</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ernst Handel</td>
                <td>Roland Mendel</td>
                <td>Austria</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Island Trading</td>
                <td>Helen Bennett</td>
                <td>UK</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
                <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
                <td>Canada</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
                <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
                <td>Italy</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>

</html>
```